# Firebase Cloud Functions Change another node's data in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to remove item from a node in for each loop on my cloud function. But it always looking only first item. I want to loop all items. Here is my codes:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
       console.log('all items');
       return thisAppDb.ref('userRemindMatches/'+child.key+'/'+compId).once('value').then(snapshot => {

            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                snapshot.ref.remove();
                console.log('match removed from this user : '+child.key);
            }
            return thisAppDb.ref('user : '+child.key+' matches removed');

        });
    });
```

As you see here, in snapshot.foreach, I am calling another ref. Node then I want to remove item from that node. It is working only once. How can I loop this for each items? (In my opinion, it occurs because of return in loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
 return thisAppDb.ref('userRemindMatches/'+child.key+'/'+compId).once('value').then(snapshot => {
```

to this:

```
 return thisAppDb.ref('userRemindMatches/'+child.key+'/'+compId).on('value',(snapshot)=> {
```

Comment: Error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Comment: @user9310000 please also upvote the answer by clicking the arrow up next to the answer, so others know that it is helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) makes it clear how the return value from your passed function is interpreted:

> function(non-null admin.database.DataSnapshot)
>
> A function that will be called for each child DataSnapshot. **The
>   callback can return true to cancel further enumeration.**

You're returning a "truthy" value, which tells forEach to stop.

Comment: so what is your suggestion

Comment: The suggestion is not to return anything at all.